# Can performance of this applescript be improved (by buffering before writing to file)

Tags: applescript, itunes

This script talks to iTunes and creates a list of all the files in the iTunes library, but if the iTunes library is large it can take a while, I think part of the reason is that it is writing to a file and I just wonder if this is the most efficient way to write to a file

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set thePath to (POSIX file "/tmp/jaikoz_itunes_model.txt")
    set fileref to open for access (thePath) with write permission
    set eof fileref to 0
    set mainLibrary to library playlist 1
    repeat with nexttrack in (get every track of mainLibrary)
        if (class of nexttrack is file track) then
            try
                set trackname to name of nexttrack
                set loc to location of nexttrack
                set locpath to POSIX path of loc
                set persistid to persistent ID of nexttrack
                set nextline to trackname & "::" & locpath & "::" & persistid
                write nextline & "\n" as "utf8" to fileref  starting at eof
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
    close access fileref
end tell
return ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use batches to make the script much faster...

```
   set maxBatch to 1000
set thePathA to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "jaikoz_itunes_model_noFormat.txt"
set thePathB to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "jaikoz_itunes_model.txt"

    tell application "iTunes"
        set mainLibrary to library playlist 1

        script s
        property theTracks : get every track of mainLibrary
    end script

    set trackBatch to {}
    set batchCount to 0

    repeat with nexttrack in s's theTracks
        if (class of nexttrack is file track) then
            try
                set trackname to name of nexttrack
                set loc to location of nexttrack
                set locpath to POSIX path of loc
                set persistid to persistent ID of nexttrack
                set end of trackBatch to trackname & "::" & locpath & "::" & persistid & linefeed
                set batchCount to batchCount + 1
                if batchCount mod maxBatch = 0 then
                    set trackBatch to trackBatch as text
                    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of trackBatch & " >> " & quoted form of thePathA
                    set trackBatch to {}
                end if
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

if trackBatch ≠ {} then
    set trackBatch to trackBatch as text
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of trackBatch & " >> " & quoted form of thePathA
    set trackBatch to {}
end if

do shell script "sed '/^$/ d' " & quoted form of thePathA & " > " & quoted form of thePathB & " ; rm " & quoted form of thePathA
```

Comment: Thanks giving it a go though unlike the original seems to fail if output file doesnt exist and IM not sure if closing file properly

Comment: The shell command to append to a file ">>" creates the file if it does not exist and closes the file after each time writing to it. What error message do you get?

Comment: I have updated path so the files are created on the desktop so you can find them quickly

Answer (score -1):

Two approaches you can test:

(Note that I've only partially tested this)

```
--loading data into memory before writing:
tell application "iTunes"
    set thePath to (POSIX file "/tmp/jaikoz_itunes_model.txt")
    set mainLibrary to library playlist 1
    set fileData to ""
    repeat with nexttrack in (get every track of mainLibrary)
        if (class of nexttrack is file track) then
            try
                set trackname to name of nexttrack
                set loc to location of nexttrack
                set locpath to POSIX path of loc
                set persistid to persistent ID of nexttrack
                set nextline to trackname & "::" & locpath & "::" & persistid
                set fileData to (fileData & nextline & return)
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
    try
    set fileref to open for access (thePath) with write permission
    write fileData to fileref
    on error e
     close access fileref
     display dialog e
    end try
    close access fileref
end tell
```

or, using do shell:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    --using raw POSIX style path below
    set mainLibrary to library playlist 1
    repeat with nexttrack in (get every track of mainLibrary)
        if (class of nexttrack is file track) then
            try
                set trackname to name of nexttrack
                set loc to location of nexttrack
                set locpath to POSIX path of loc
                set persistid to persistent ID of nexttrack
                set nextline to trackname & "::" & locpath & "::" & persistid
                --but caution: if there are any single quotes in the line of data, 
                -- you'll have a problem; you'd have to replace "'" with "\'" in it first
                do shell script ("echo " & (quoted form of nextline) & ">>/tmp/jaikoz_itunes_model.txt")
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: echo '" & nextline & "' should be echo " & quoted form of nextline & "

Comment: two approaches without comments dont make an answer

Comment: Both approaches, as commented on in approach 1, load data into memory before writing, and the 2nd uses do shell, which is also commented on. These are two attempts to help address performance, which you may not consider good enough or efficient or even worth an answer (I guess I'd agree with the last and say these should've been comments). So ... sorry.